# Yodlee refresh on an already-active MFA account

Tags: yodlee

Re: Yodlee *site*-based API

a) I know that when adding an MFA account you are supposed to trigger /jsonsdk/Refresh/startSiteRefresh. But if an account is already added and already active, and I want to trigger a manual refresh to get new data, is /jsonsdk/Refresh/startSiteRefresh the correct API to use?

b) When I do use /jsonsdk/Refresh/startSiteRefresh for a manual refresh, I do not want to trigger the whole MFA flow, I simply want to pull new data if possible. So which refreshMode do I specify "MFA" or "NORMAL"?

I ask this, because I used "MFA" mode and it failed with a 522 (timeout) error due to a new security question. But when Yodlee runs the nightly refresh, the same condition will result in a 506 or 518; not a 522. Maybe I am supposed to specify "NORMAL" even for "MFA" accounts for a manual refresh?

Answer (score 0):

You need not pass the refresh mode in the startSiteRefresh API. When you call this API for a siteAccountID the response will tell you if the MFA is required or not. Below fields can be used from the response.

```
"siteRefreshMode":{
      "refreshModeId":1,
      "refreshMode":"MFA"
   }
```

Depending on the refreshMode you can follow the MFA flow or Normal flow.

When you trigger this API you will have to flow the complete flow to get the latest data or else the refresh will fail and data will not be updated.

Refer   - [startSiteRefresh](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/startSiteRefresh) for the API and [Refresh Flow](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow/Refresh_Site_Account) for refreshing an account.

> I ask this, because I used "MFA" mode and it failed with a 522 (timeout) error due to a new security question. But when Yodlee runs the nightly refresh, the same condition will result in a 506 or 518; not a 522

This is because in case of manual refresh you as a user is not answering the question asked at the end site and hence our server identifies it as no response from the user and hence 522 error code. When it's automatic refresh from Yodlee's end and a new question is encountered the error code is 518.